# Xamarin Forms compilation error in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to make a simple xamairn form apllication by folling steps

[image]l
after creating project when compile it

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a compilation error.  Your solution should contain multiple projects - a PCL and one or more platform specific (iOS, Android, Windows Phone) projects.  The PCL is just a library - you cannot run it.  Instead you need to right click on one of the platform projects and select "Set as Startup Project".  Then when you run your solution Visual Studio will execute that project in the appropriate simulator/emulator.

Comment: How can I add the Portable Class Library? I get 1400+ errors when I just create a blank Xamarin.Forms application and debug it as it is. Is it because of I have not add portable class library to project, as you say?